# Problem trying to use provider with nested BottomNavigation Bar for my state- Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, flutter-state

I'm trying to learn proper state management with provider, I've got an issue that I'm having trouble with here. From what I can tell, I'm doing everything as per instructions in three separate provider tutorials. I'm also using it successfully for my dataTable with no issues. However I keep getting error messages and failures when trying to use provider for my BottomNavigationBar and my appBar up the widget tree.

I want to keep my bottom nav bar separate from my "zero screen" state. So I'm setting an int with bottom nav bar button presses according to index, this is supposed to update my GlobalData pageSelection Index. I then access this up the tree for the ternary operators. But I get a weird error saying that its out of the widget tree...

I tried doing what the error suggestion states with no luck.

Any help appreciated!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pageSelectionIndex = 0;

  void updatePageSelection(int index) {
    pageSelectionIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

BottomNavBar

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/models/global_data.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/screens/balance_screen.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/screens/subtract_screen.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/screens/add_screen.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/screens/inquiry_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _tabPages = <Widget>[
      AddScreen(),
      SubtractScreen(),
      BalanceScreen(),
      InquiryScreen()
    ];

    final _navBarItems = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), label: 'Add'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle), label: 'Subtract'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on_rounded), label: 'Balance'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), label: 'Inquiry'),
    ];

    assert(_tabPages.length == _navBarItems.length);
    final navBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _navBarItems,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
      currentIndex: _currentTabIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: (int index) {
        Provider.of<GlobalData>(context).updatePageSelection(index);
        setState(() {
          _currentTabIndex = index;
        });
      },
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabPages[_currentTabIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: navBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Zero Screen:

```
///
///
/// Holds bottom nav bar which in turn switches through screens

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/models/global_data.dart';
import 'package:fp_provider_demo_one/widgets/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ZeroScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _selectedIndex = Provider.of<GlobalData>(context).pageSelectionIndex;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (_selectedIndex == 0)
            ? Text('Add')
            : (_selectedIndex == 1)
                ? Text('Subtract')
                : (_selectedIndex == 2)
                    ? Text('Balance')
                    : Text('Inquiry'),
        backgroundColor: (_selectedIndex == 0)
            ? Colors.green
            : (_selectedIndex == 1)
                ? Colors.red
                : (_selectedIndex == 2)
                    ? Colors.blue
                    : Colors.orange,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<GlobalData>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: BottomNavBar(state: _BottomNavBarState#38ad7)
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 262 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:262:7)
#3      _BottomNavBarState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fp_provider_demo_one/widgets/bottom_nav_bar.dart:49:18)
#4      _BottomNavigationBarState._createTiles.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart:974:26)
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:991:20)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#035fc
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(144.0, 783.0)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(46.5, 21.5)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: use `Provider.of<GlobalData>(context, listen: false).updatePageSelection`

```
onTap: (int index) {
        Provider.of<GlobalData>(context, listen: false)
            .updatePageSelection(index);
```

Step 2 : put `ChangeNotifierProvider` in `main()`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GlobalData(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class GlobalData extends ChangeNotifier {
  int pageSelectionIndex = 0;

  void updatePageSelection(int index) {
    pageSelectionIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _tabPages = <Widget>[
      AddScreen(),
      SubtractScreen(),
      BalanceScreen(),
      InquiryScreen()
    ];

    final _navBarItems = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), label: 'Add'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle), label: 'Subtract'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on_rounded), label: 'Balance'),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), label: 'Inquiry'),
    ];

    assert(_tabPages.length == _navBarItems.length);
    final navBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _navBarItems,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
      currentIndex: _currentTabIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: (int index) {
        Provider.of<GlobalData>(context, listen: false)
            .updatePageSelection(index);
        setState(() {
          _currentTabIndex = index;
        });
      },
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabPages[_currentTabIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: navBar,
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GlobalData(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ZeroScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ZeroScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _selectedIndex = Provider.of<GlobalData>(context).pageSelectionIndex;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (_selectedIndex == 0)
            ? Text('Add')
            : (_selectedIndex == 1)
                ? Text('Subtract')
                : (_selectedIndex == 2)
                    ? Text('Balance')
                    : Text('Inquiry'),
        backgroundColor: (_selectedIndex == 0)
            ? Colors.green
            : (_selectedIndex == 1)
                ? Colors.red
                : (_selectedIndex == 2)
                    ? Colors.blue
                    : Colors.orange,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class AddScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("AddScreen"));
  }
}

class SubtractScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("SubtractScreen"));
  }
}

class BalanceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("BalanceScreen"));
  }
}

class InquiryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("InquiryScreen"));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best way.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! What was I doing wrong here? Would be great to learn from this as well as having a solution :)

Comment: @RobbB, for button, you can see error message. This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried declaring your provider variable outside onTap?like:

```
final provider = Provider.of<GlobalData>(context);
```

```
onTap:(index){
provider.updatePageSelection(index);
}
```

the other possibility is that `context` cant be reached properly in `onTap` and as it says in the log you should set `listen: false` when declaring provider like:

```
Provider.of<GlobalData>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: Tried both suggestions, no luck. I get the following error for both: `Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GlobalData> above this BottomNavBar Widget`

Comment: @RobbB do you provide the Provider in the widget tree like: `ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => GlobalData (),
      child: Scaffold()) `

Comment: That is way over my head. No I am not providing it like that.

Comment: @RobbB without providing it you cant access it

Comment: I think I understand what you’re saying now. I will try that